# Fazer um input receber um valor menor que outro

Tags: php, javascript, html5

```html
<input type="number" name="total" value="25" required>
<input type="number" name="valor-em-dinheiro" class="form-control text-right" required>
```

Tenho dois input aonde o primeiro receber o valor de 25, queria saber como fazer o segundo não receber um valor menor que o primeiro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for fazer isso de forma dinâmica, utilize JavaScript com o evento `blur`, igualando o valor caso seja menor.

O `min` pode ser usado para efeito de validação se você está utilizando um formulário a ser submetido.

Se não for este o caso, pode utilizar o evento `blur` abaixo:

```js
document.querySelector("[name=valor-em-dinheiro]").onblur = function(){

   // valor do primeiro input. Se for vazio vira 0
   var total = document.querySelector("[name=total]").value || 0;

   // valor do segundo input
   var dindin = this.value;

   // se o segundo for menor que o primeiro, iguala
   if(Number(dindin) < total) this.value = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="total" value="25" required>
<br>
Digite um valor menor e tecle TAB:
<input type="number" name="valor-em-dinheiro" class="form-control text-right" required>
```

Se for submeter o formulário, pode alterar o `min` de forma dinâmica:

```js
document.querySelector("[name=total]").oninput = function(){
   // altera o min do segundo input de acordo com o valor digitado
   document.querySelector("[name=valor-em-dinheiro]").min = this.value;
}

document.querySelector("[name=valor-em-dinheiro]").oninput = function(){

   // seleciona o primeiro input
   var total = document.querySelector("[name=total]");

   // altera o min de acordo com o valor de total
   this.min = total.value;

}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="number" name="total" value="25" required>
   <input type="number" name="valor-em-dinheiro" class="form-control text-right" required>
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: mas e pra proibir o usuário de digitar um numero menor essa função de digitar o tab pra poder ativa a função não ficaria legal pra mim.

Comment: Entendo. Vc vai submeter esse formulário?

Comment: Sim, irei submeter

Comment: O problema é o seguinte: se o cara quiser digitar "200", é maior que 25, só que ao digitar o número "2" inicial, é menor que 25. Por isso tem que ter algum evento final para saber que valor o cara digitou. Quando ele faz um blur, é porque ele já digitou o valor que queria e saiu no input.

Comment: Ele não tem que teclar em TAB. O TAB foi só um exemplo para sair do campo.

Comment: ahhh entendi, agr se eu quisesse fazer isso com uma div in vez do input

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86745/discussion-between-vision-development-and-sam).

Comment: Costumo colocar o gatilho no evento `change`. Independente do cara sair do campo (blur) ou submeter o formulário (submit), o `change` será executado.

Comment: @LipESprY O problema é que o change só tem efeito nas setas, e olha que o IE nem seta tem. Então ele terá o mesmo efeito que o blur, porque o change só é disparado quando tira o foco do campo.

Comment: @Sam Sempre usei o change. Fiquei curioso com sua resposta e fui testar! Coloquei 2 gatilhos em um input: change e blur. Editei o input e pressionei Enter (submit). No Chrome foi disparado apenas o change. No IE foram disparados ambos...

Answer (score 4):

Use o atributo `[min][1]`.

```html
<input type="number" name="total" value="25" required>
<input type="number" name="valor-em-dinheiro" class="form-control text-right" required min="25">
```

Comment: Mas o valor do primeiro e dinâmico

Comment: Você pode alterar o valor mínimo com JS também, fazendo `document.getElementById("elemento").min = "25";`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('[name=valor-em-dinheiro]').onchange = function() {
    console.log('change disparado');
    if(this.value < document.querySelector('[name=total]').value) {
        alert('Valor em dinheiro deve ser maior ou igual ao total!');
        // ...
    }
}
// No Chrome (atualizado) não é acionado o blur caso o usuário pressione "enter" para submeter o formulário.
//document.querySelector('[name=valor-em-dinheiro]').onblur = function() {
//    console.log('blur disparado');
//}
document.querySelector('[id=formul]').onsubmit = function(ev) {
    if(document.querySelector('[name=valor-em-dinheiro]').value < document.querySelector('[name=total]').value) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit interrompido');
    } else {
        ev.preventDefault(); // LEMBRE-SE DE COMENTAR ESTA LINHA APÓS TESTAR.
        console.log('submit não interrompido');
    }
}
```

```html
  <form action="/dev" method="get" id="formul">
      <input type="number" name="total" value="25" required>
      <input type="number" name="valor-em-dinheiro" class="form-control text-right" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Use como exemplo. Altere conforme sua necessidade. A fim de testar, coloquei um `alert()` e um `preventDefault()` caso o usuário tente submeter o formulário com o valor menor.

Dessa forma (`onchange`), o gatilho será acionado até mesmo quando o usuário pressionar *enter* após definir o valor do segundo campo.